# How to compress a string in React Native?

Tags: string, reactjs, react-native, compression

Let, I have a string with 20 characters. Then, I need to compress it to a string with a length of 3 or 5 characters. Again, when I need the original string back, I should be able to decompress the compressed string and get the original string.

Is it possible to do? If yes, how to do it in REACT NATIVE? Can you please suggest me a good solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this, may help you:

```
var lz = require('lz-string');
let before = lz.compress("bla bla bla")
let after = lz.decompress(before)
console.log(before, before.length);// ᆁ낆J鵀 4
console.log(after, after.length); // bla bla bla 11
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Try [Unishox String Compression](https://github.com/siara-cc/Unishox_JS) library.

This library was developed specifically to individually compress and decompress short strings. In general, compression utilities such as `zip`, `gzip` do not compress short strings well and often expand them. So that was the reason to develop [Unishox](https://github.com/siara-cc/Unishox/blob/master/Unishox_Article_2.pdf?raw=true).

Sample code:

```
var usx = require("unishox2.js")
var my_str = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
var out_buf = new Uint8Array(100); // A buffer with arbitrary length
var out_len = usx.unishox2_compress_simple(my_str, my_str.length, out_buf);
var out_str = usx.unishox2_decompress_simple(out_buf, out_len);
console.log(out_str);
```

Unishox is [available for C](https://github.com/siara-cc/Unishox), [Javascript](https://github.com/siara-cc/Unishox_JS) and [Python](https://github.com/tweedge/unishox2-py3) and [found to be quite stable](https://github.com/tweedge/unishox2-py3#integration-tests) by users. [See here](https://github.com/tweedge/unishox2-py3#performance) for a comprehensive performance test by the person who implemented it in Python.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this library and the [Unishox compression method](https://github.com/siara-cc/Unishox/blob/master/Unishox_Article_2.pdf?raw=true).

Another similar method is [Smaz](https://github.com/personalcomputer/smaz.js) but is less efficient and does not support Unicode.